# Windows Media Player functionality for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, music, media-player

I have way to many music files to bother with setting up playlists. Especially since my files locations keeps changing as I move stuff around and swap between different computers, different mount points, and even different Operating Systems!

So managing my media with any application is doomed to failure.

However, since I still want to listen to the music I usually just select all the files I want to play at a time and then right-click to open them in a media player. Works great in windows media player and places all the tracks in a temp playlist on the sidebar.

Fails in ubuntu using Rhythmbox since it doesn't understand "temp" playlists and just keeps adding files to your FULL listing of all sings on your whole computer. I have over three copies of some tracks now in my audio collection - and all of them are now invalid because the location of the files has changed.

So what media player (for Ubuntu) works well with just temporary playlists and will allow me to open up my files without adding them to a collection?

**Failed tests:**
Alsaplayer opens up file in a new player
VLC and MPlayer require two windows to be open to see the playlist and media window.

Answer (score 1):

Try Totem; it doesn't try to a music library manager.

You may also have some luck setting up a UPNP/DNLA or DAAP server on one machine and using it as a media server.

Comment: I'm showing Totem installed - but I can't find the app anywhere. Strange....

Answer (score 1):

Other options:

- [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/)
- [Mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu)

Comment: Both VLC and MPlayer require two windows to be open to see the playlist and media window. I'm want just a single app that I can keep in the background without it cluttering my task bar.